# Rails 4: Render partial with variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, partials

I have the following partial:

```
<tr class="profile-row">
    <td class="profile-header"><%= attribute %></td>
    <% for week in @weeks %>
    <td><%= week.<%= field %> %></td> <!-- where it fails -->
    <% end %>
</tr>
```

...and I'd like to be able to supply 2 variables, `attribute` and `field`.  When I try to render the partial with the following:

```
<%= render 'foo', attribute: 'Current Weight', field: 'current_weight' %>
```

...I want:

```
<tr class="profile-row">
    <td class="profile-header">Current Weight</td>
    <% for week in @weeks %>
    <td><%= week.current_weight %></td> <!-- where it fails -->
    <% end %>
</tr>
```

...but this fails with `syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN...`.  I understand this isn't the correct way to supply a variable, but how should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest ERB tags like this:

```
<%= week.<%= field %> %>
```

Instead do this:

```
<%= week %>.<%= field %>
```

Whatever you put inside ERB tags is Ruby. So your code is saying "Run the Ruby code `week.<%= field` and stick the result here." But that is not valid Ruby syntax.

Or if `field` contains the name of the attribute, you could do this:

```
<%= week.send field.to_sym %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest erb tags.
If your variables are strings you can concatenate them.

```
<%= week + "." + field%>
```

If that throws an error try this

```
<%= week.to_s + "." + field.to_s%>
```